# Command blocks to replace the functionality of /fill etc

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

Is there any way we can use command blocks to replace the functionality of /fill?
for example if the user types /fill, he should be given a potato or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible currently with command blocks: try using plugins

Comment: please tell me what plugin to use. I use Forge on my server